# Height of tabularx containing a multicol

Tags: multicol, tabularx

I would like to have a vertical label to the left of a multicolumn block of text. The easiest way to do this I have found is using a `multicol` environment as one of the cells in a `tabularx` table. The problem is that the resulting `tabularx` has too much vertical whitespace, presumably because the multicol environment pads itself too much. I am open to solutions that do not use the strategy I show below. MWE with two attempts:

```
\documentclass[article,oneside,letterpaper]{memoir}
    \usepackage{multicol}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{lipsum}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X  }
        \cline{1-1}
        \multirow{1}{*}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Margin Label~}}&\\
            & \begin{multicols}{3}
            \lipsum*[1-2]
            \end{multicols} \\
        \cline{1-1}
    \end{tabularx}

    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X  }
        \cline{1-1}
        \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Margin Label~} & 
            \begin{multicols*}{3}
            \lipsum*[1-2]
            \end{multicols*}\\
        \cline{1-1}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `multicols*` inside a box issues a warning and the package uses `multicols` anyway.

The main problem is that an `X` column does a `\parbox` that doesn't remove vertical space around the `multicols` environment. You should also rotate with `r` as the reference point.

```
\documentclass[article,oneside,letterpaper]{memoir}
\usepackage[latin]{babel} % just to avoid most Underfull box messages
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | l | X  }
\cline{1-1}
\rotatebox[origin=r]{90}{Margin Label\ } &
  \begin{minipage}[t]{\hsize} % a minipage removes almost all vertical space
  \hrule height 0pt % set a reference point
  \vspace{-\baselineskip} % remove an extra vertical space
  \begin{multicols}{3}
  \lipsum*[1-2]
  \end{multicols}
  \end{minipage}
\\
\cline{1-1}
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]